# Laplace transform and general method of solving DE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, self-learning, laplace-transform

$y"+3y'+2y=g(t), y(0)=0, y'(0)=-2,$where,

$g\left( t \right) = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}2&{\hspace{0.25in}t < 6}\\t&{\hspace{0.25in}6 \le t < 10}\\4&{\hspace{0.25in}t \ge 10}\end{array}} \right.$

Now, Author got solutions as follows
$f(t)=\frac12-e^{-t}+\frac12e^{-2t}$

$g(t)=-\frac34+\frac12 t+e^{-t}-\frac14 e^{-2t}$

$h(t)=2e^{-t}-2e^{-2t}$.

Now the author says If we had not used Laplace transform, For 1st part of g(t), we get solution $y_1(t)=2f(t)-h(t)$

For 2nd part of g(t), we get solution $y_2(t)=2f(t)-h(t)+4f(t-6)+g(t-6)$

For 3rd part of g(t), we get solution $y_3(t)=2f(t)-h(t)+4f(t-6)+g(t-6)-6f(t-10)-g(t-10)$
 Now i want to verify $y_2(t)$ when t=7, How can i verify it?

What would be the initial conditions? Are they $y(7)=y_1(7)$ and $y'(7)=y'_1(7)$

Note that if you need any additional information, it will be provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need to have the differentiable phase change at $t=6$. That is
$$
y_2(6)=y_1(6)\\
y_2'(6)=y_1'(6)
$$
To understand the components, check that, $L$ being the differential operator on the left side, $L(y)=y''+3y'+2y$, then
\begin{align}
L(f)&=1&f(0)&=0&f'(0)&=0\\
L(g)&=t&g(0)&=0&g'(0)&=0\\
L(h)&=0&h(0)&=0&h'(0)&=2\\
\end{align}
so that the first two provide the components for the right side, and $h$ accounts for the initial condition.

Comment: After doing some calculation work on my laptop, I obtained the correct verification of $y_2(t)$ and $y_3(t)$.

Comment: I didn't understand $L(f)=1,L(g)=t,L(h)=0$. Would you explain what are those computations?